# how to use mplfinance.plot to draw a plot overlapping an another plot

Tags: python, mplfinance

I have a dataframe, columns are open, high, low, close, volume.
In the old api availability, from mplfinance.original_flavor import candlestick_ohlc. I can write as this:

```py
candlestick_ohlc(
    ax,
    quotes,
    width=0.2,
    colorup='k',
    colordown='r',
    alpha=1.0,
)
```

ax can be a plot that contains some scatter.
For example,

```py
quotes = {'dateframe':['2022-01-01','2022-01-02'],
          'open':[10,11],
          'high':[11,12],
          'low':[9,10],
          'close':[10,11].
```

ax1 has a `scatter:['2022-01-01',10]`

And using `candlestick_ohlc`, `ax = ax1`, the two plots can overlap.

But how to use the new API mplfinance to attain this method?

Comment: See this for a detailed [explanation](https://github.com/matplotlib/mplfinance/blob/master/examples/addplot.ipynb). The list of scatter plots must have the same length of candles. So the list is a list with np.NaN inserted for unnecessary items.

Comment: Thanks, I know this. I wonder is there any method that could get the two plots overlapped without a list. With candlestick_ohlc, the ax is customized.

Comment: @pekinghua ... I don't understand what you mean by a "method that could get the two plots overlapped without a list."  The data for the second plot has to come from somewhere.  Can you please clarify what you are asking?  WIth the new mplfinance api, the second data set is on the same `ax` ... the only difference is you do not have to worry about the Axes, mplfinance does that for you.  Please clarify what you are asking.

Comment: @DanielGoldfarb Yeah, I just got it. With the new mplfinance api, using the parameter ax is the same as the old api. I got the question as I am not familiar with plt.subplots(). Thank you very much for helping edit the question! As I am the first time user, thank you for your guidance.